# Why does this code run so much faster when compiled with optimizations on?

Tags: optimization, rust

I've coded a genetic algorithm in Rust to get familiar with Rust.
When I ran the code, I found out that there was an extreme performance difference between (`cargo run`) and (`cargo run --release`) version.
I found out that the code for creating randomly initialized genes was responsible for it.

I searched if there is a way to have a look at the code that is optimized by the Rust compiler and found out that it was possible on Rust Playground. So I went for it and was greeted by a bunch of Assembly Code, which I have no idea how to read.

The following code is the one that I fed to the Rust playground. (I'm sorry that the code is very dirty. I am quite new to programming.)

When compiled without optimizations(`cargo run`), it takes 160 seconds to run on average.

When compiled with optimizations(`cargo run --release`) it takes 3 seconds to run on average.

What are the exact optimization method that the compiler might be performing to cause this huge performance difference?

```
extern crate rand;

use rand::Rng;
use std::time::Instant;

fn make_genepool(position_list: &Vec<Vec<i8>>, size: i32) -> Vec<Vec<i8>>{
    let mut genelist:Vec<Vec<i8>> = Vec::new();
    let position_len = position_list.len();
    let mut rand = rand::thread_rng();
    let mut gene_rand:Vec<Vec<i8>> = Vec::new();
    for i in 0..position_len{
        let mut gene_insert:Vec<i8> = Vec::new();
        let avail_move_len = position_list[i].len();
        for _ in 0..size{
            gene_insert.push(position_list[i][rand.gen_range(0, avail_move_len)]);
        }
        gene_rand.push(gene_insert);
    }
    
    for i in 0..size as usize{
        let mut genelist_insert:Vec<i8> = Vec::new();
        for j in 0..position_len{
            genelist_insert.push(gene_rand[j][i]);
        }
        genelist.push(genelist_insert);
    }

return genelist;
}

fn main(){
    let mut rand = rand::thread_rng();

    let mut test_data:Vec<Vec<i8>> = Vec::new();
    for i in 0..4520{
        let mut temp:Vec<i8> = Vec::new();
        for j in 0..rand.gen_range(1, 9){
            temp.push(rand.gen_range(1, 9));
        }
        test_data.push(temp);
    }

    let now = Instant::now();
    let ans = make_genepool(&test_data, 16384);
    println!("Time passed: {}", now.elapsed().as_secs_f64());
}
```

Comment: It does exactly what the name states... [optimizes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) the generated output.

Comment: @Herohtar I am pretty sure that the compiler did not optimize the ans variable away because it is unused, since if it did, the output of that code(time taken to run make_genepool()) should have not differed whether the optimization is on or not. (If that was what you were saying by "optimizes the generated output"). I was curious about what exact optimization method did the compiler perform to cause a huge performance difference.

Comment: There is no simple answer to this question. Generating optimized machine code from source code is a science in itself, and in the past decades many smart people have come up with many smart ideas to generate fast machine code - so there is a huge difference between a straightforward translation of source code to machine code, and highly optimized code where all the optimization tricks have been applied. This is to be expected, and is not something that's specific to your program. StackOverflow is not the right place to give you a course about machine code optimization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to **compare the assembly code of both optimized and unoptimised code** to know for sure what its really doing.

But it may be:

**Range checking:** If you use a constant (for example 4520 in your code), then range checks are unnecessary.

**Loop unrolling:** If the compiler knows many types each loop runs, it might simply convert the loop body into the same code multiple times.

Other things like inlining functions etc.

To make your code run faster, you could do exactly what the compiler is doing, but its better to just let the compiler do it. There is a reason that that the compiler was designed to optimize your code.

If you simply want to write more efficient code, focus on:

1. Making sure your algorithm for your use case is optimal. Algorithms perform differently depending on the data fed in, so even though theoretically one algorithm may be optimal, for your data perhaps you are getting worst performance and another algorithm may be more suitable.
2. Understand what is happening under the hood when you create objects, destroy them etc (memory management). This will require you to study the language to understand what its doing for you. But the effort of writing the most efficient code so the compiler doesn't have to guess may not be worth your time. For example there are many techniques compilers use such as branch prediction etc, which would make you doing it yourself really tedious. Its best to optimize only if you really need it, after your code is already working properly.

In the end, is this really worth your time ? Maybe your time would be better off focusing on just getting your code to work, and then letting the compiler optimize it for you. Over time you will learn things through experience anyway and write more efficient code (hopefully).

If this answer helps, please mark it as correct.